# What is the difference Between Active User & Unique User in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

What is the difference Between Active User & Unique User in Firebase? 
What is the definition for Active User & Unique User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An active user is one who has engaged with your app in the foreground of their device.

Some users trigger events which do not imply engagement (e.g. when they dismiss a push notification or uninstall your app).  They are not necessarily active users, but you can compute the distinct count of users (i.e. unique users) who dismiss push notifications or uninstall your app.

Comment: Hi Steve: Below query is working fine. but if i add  "app_info.id" to below query, it is not fetching result. Pls. help SELECT event_date,event_name,count( distinct user_pseudo_id ) AS active_users
FROM (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id,
  event_date,event_name,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190401'  AND '20190407' and key = 
      "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time
  FROM `<table>*`
) 
WHERE engagement_time > 0 group by 1,2